# how to. check background color image

Tags: flutter, dart

**when I take icon color white on profile but my profile color white too so my Icon do not show , that why how to check background image**

Comment: Add a grayish color background behind your icon. so it will be visible even on top of white color profile image.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Check Pixel Color of the Image ,
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ImagePixels(
imageProvider: image,
builder: (context, img) {
Color topLeftColor = img.pixelColorAt(0, 0);
Text("Pixel color at top-left: $topLeftColor.");
);}}